# Regex alternation/or operator (foo|bar) in GNU or BSD Sed

Tags: shell, sed, regular-expression

I cannot seem to make it work.  GNU sed documentation says to escape the pipe, but that doesn't work, nor does using a straight pipe without the escape.  Adding parens makes no difference.

```sh
$ echo 'cat
dog
pear
banana
cat
dog' | sed 's/cat|dog/Bear/g'
cat
dog
pear
banana
cat
dog

$ echo 'cat
dog
pear
banana
cat
dog' | sed 's/cat\|dog/Bear/g'
cat
dog
pear
banana
cat
dog
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[By default `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02) uses [POSIX Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), which don't include the `|` alternation operator. You can switch it into using [Extended Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_03), which do include `|` alternation, with `-E` (or `-r` in some older versions of some implementations). You can use:

```
echo 'cat dog pear banana cat dog' | sed -E -e 's/cat|dog/Bear/g'
```

and it will work on compliant systems. (`-e` optionally marks the sed script itself - you can leave it out, it just guards against some kinds of mistake)

Portability to very old `sed`s is complicated, but you can also [switch to `awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_04) if you need it, which uses EREs everywhere.

Comment: The three BSDs you mentioned *all* support the `-r` option as a synonym of `-E` for compatibility with GNU sed. OpenBSD's and OS X's `sed -E` will interpret the escaped pipe as a literal pipe, not as alternation operator. [Here's a working link](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?sed) to the NetBSD man page and [here's one](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-5.5/man1/sed.1?&manpath=OpenBSD%2d5%2e5&arch=amd64&query=sed) for OpenBSD that isn't ten years old.

Comment: OSX supports `-E`: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html

Comment: GNU sed supports `-E` https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-_002dE.

Comment: I gather that `-E` tells it to use extended regular expressions; what does `-e` do here? For me on MSYS2/Windows and MacOS Catalina, omitting `-e` works and produces the same output . . .

Comment: The back references do not work (\1, \2 etc) when using -E. I can't use sed -E -e"s/\\(cat|dog\\)/\1 - Bear/g". Is there any workaround for that?

Comment: I think it is important to note that while you mention POSIX `sed` and then recommend `-E`, POSIX `sed` still does **not** support `-E` as of 2022.  There is also no indication that it will be in the next version either.  `-E` is still a BSD / GNU extension.

Comment: @JoeJobs with `-E` you need to remote the backslash in front of the parenthesis.

Answer (score 15):

This happens because `(a|b)` is an extended regular expression, not a Basic Regular Expression.  Use the `-E` option to deal with this.

```
echo 'cat
dog
pear
banana
cat
dog'|sed -E 's/cat|dog/Bear/g'
```

From the `sed` man page:

> ```
>  -E      Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular
>          expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).
> ```

Note that `-r` is another flag for the same thing, but `-E` is more portable and will even be in the next version of POSIX specifications.

Answer (score 12):

The portable way to do this - and the more efficient way - is with addresses. You can do this:

```
printf %s\\n cat dog pear banana cat dog |
sed -e '/cat/!{/dog/!b' -e '}' -e 'c\
Bear'
```

In this way if the line does not contain the string *cat* and does not contain the string *dog* `sed` `b`ranches out of the script, autoprints its current line and pulls in the next to begin the next cycle. It therefore does not perform the next instruction - which in this example `c`hanges the entire line to read *Bear* but it could do anything.

It's probably worth noting also that any statement following the `!b` in that `sed` command can *only* match on a line containing either the string `dog` or `cat` - so you can perform further tests without any danger of matching a line that doesn't - which means you can now apply rules to only one or the other as well.

But that's next. Here's output from the above command:

```
###OUTPUT###
Bear
Bear
pear
banana
Bear
Bear
```

You can also portably implement a lookup table with backreferences.

```
printf %s\\n cat dog pear banana cat dog |
sed '1{x;s/^/ cat dog /;x;}
G;s/^\(.*\)\n.* \1 .*/Bear/;P;d'
```

It's a lot more work to setup for this simple example case, but it can make for much more flexible `sed` scripts in the long run.

In the first line I e`x`change hold space and pattern space then insert the string *`<space>`cat`<space>`dog`<space>`* into hold space before e`x`changing them back.

From then on and on every following line I `G`et hold space appended to pattern space, then check to see if all of the characters from the beginning of the line until the newline I just added at the end match a string surrounded by spaces after it. If so I replace the entire lot with *Bear* and if not there is no harm done because I next `P`rint only up to the first occurring newline in pattern space then `d`elete it all.

```
###OUTPUT###
Bear
Bear
pear
banana
Bear
Bear
```

And when I say flexible, I mean it. Here it is replacing *cat* with *BrownBear* and *dog* with *BlackBear*:

```
printf %s\\n cat dog pear banana cat dog |
sed '1{x;s/^/ 1cat Brown 2dog Black /;x;}
     G;s/^\(.*\)\n.* [0-9]\1 \([^ ]*\) .*/\2Bear/;P;d'

###OUTPUT###
BrownBear
BlackBear
pear
banana
BrownBear
BlackBear
```

You can of course expand a great deal on the contents of the lookup table - I picked up the idea from [Greg Ubben's](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/tutorials/lookup_table_counter.txt) usenet emails on the subject when, in the 90's, he described how he constructed a crude calculator out of a single `sed s///` statement.

Comment: phew, +1. You have a penchant for thinking out of the box I must say

Comment: @1_CR - See my last edit - not my idea - which is not to say that I don't appreciate that and consider it a compliment. But I like to give credit where it's due.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a technique that does not make use of any implementation specific options to `sed` (e.g. `-E` , `-r`). Instead of describing the pattern as a single regex `cat|dog`, we can simply run `sed` twice:

```
echo 'cat
dog
pear
banana
cat
dog' | sed -e 's/cat/Bear/g' -e 's/dog/Bear/g'
```

It's an obvious workaround really, but worth sharing. It naturally generalizes to more than two pattern strings, though a very long chain of `sed`'s isn't too good looking.

I often use `sed -i` (note though that this is not implemented in all implementations) to make changes in files. Here, a long list of pattern strings may be incorporated nicely, as each temporary result is saved to the file:

```
for pattern in cat dog owl; do
    sed -i "s/${pattern}/Bear/g" myfile
done
```

Comment: Note that `-E` will be in the next version of the POSIX standard. `-i` is not standard though, and there are conflicting APIs among the implementations that support it. Also, you don't need 2 `sed` invocations here. `sed 's/cat/Bear/g; s/dog/Bear/g'` would be enough. Beware though that a `sed 's/cat/Bear/g' | sed 's/rat/Bear/g'` (or the one invocation with two `s` commands) would change `catat` to `BeaBear`.

Comment: `sed -i` is non-standard, and where supported doesn't *work the same in all implementations* at all. Two implemented (GNU and FreeBSD) implemented that perl-style option independently and differently in the early 2000s, most other implementations have copied the GNU way since.

Answer (score 2):

this is a pretty old question, but in case someone wants to try, there is a fairly low effort way to do this in sed with sed files. Each option can be listed on a separate line, and sed will evaluate each one. It's a logical equivalent of or. For example, to remove lines that contain a certain code:

you can say : `sed -E '/^\/\*!(40103|40101|40111).*\/;$/d'`

or put this in your sed file:

```
/^\/\*!40103.*\/;$/d
/^\/\*!40101.*\/;$/d
/^\/\*!40111.*\/;$/d
```

Answer (score -2):

While the title is referencing [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) or [BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1) [sed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), a moldy version of [awk](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) should always work.  All `awk` implementations are expected to support EREs per the POSIX specification.

`$ cat yearly.txt`

```
2020
2021
2022
2023
```

`$ awk '{sub(/2020|2021/,"old"); print}' yearly.txt`

```
old
old
2022
2023
```

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html

Comment: `-E` will be in the next POSIX version though (currently in draft stage).

Comment: Fair enough.  Can I (or others) read the draft proposals without a login?  I am interested to read about some of changes.

Comment: I believe you need a login (free) to get access to the drafts. But the bug tracker [with the accepted resolution](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=528) is publicly available.

Comment: The `-e` option has never been for enabling extended regular expressions, in any `sed` implementation, ever. And no answer here is claiming so either.