# Does FreeBSD contain multiple variants of basic regex?

Tags: regular-expression, freebsd, portability, compatibility

`grep` and `sed` are both described as using "basic regex" ("BRE") by default. BRE is well described [here](http://matt.might.net/articles/sculpting-text).

But consider this output:

```
# echo '    aaaaa   ' | grep '\(aaaaa\|bbbbb\)'
    aaaaa
# echo '    aaaaa   ' | sed '/\(aaaaa\|bbbbb\)/ s/ /_/g'
    aaaaa
```

In the first command, the `\( ... \| ... \)` syntax **clearly acted** as `(X OR Y)`, since the output passed `grep`.

In the second command, the `\( ... \| ... \)` syntax **clearly didn't act** as `(X OR Y)`, because the spaces weren't changed to underscores.

(By contrast, **both** commands recognise `\+` as "one or more repetitions")

What's gone on? Why do there seem to be two flavours of BRE in FreeBSD, one of which recognises syntax that the other doesn't?

The deeper question is, many projects look at BRE to provide portability to other unix-like systems. But this suggests that even BREs aren't likely to be the same across platforms, if they can't even be the same *within* individual platforms. Argh?

Comment: Your sed example works as you expected on Linux (WSL) with GNU sed 4.2.2. Maybe FreeBSD has a different or non-GNU sed? Sadly, for maximum portability you might need to use the `--posix` options

Comment: For a more general overview, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, yes, the BSDs have their own (non-GNU) implementations of all basic UNIX tools -- not just `sed`, *everything*. Whereas Linux is just a kernel, the BSDs are complete operating systems -- kernel, libc, POSIX-mandated utilities, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The description in the linked article is wrong.

[The actual POSIX definition](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_02) states that:

> The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped <backslash> ( '\' ) is undefined, except for *[`(){}`, digits and inside a bracket expression]*

And ordinary characters are defined as any except the BRE special characters `.[^$*` and the backslash itself.

So, unlike that page claims, the `\+` is undefined in BRE, and so is `\|`.

Some regex implementations define them as the same as ERE `+` and `|` though, particularly the GNU ones. But you shouldn't count on that, stick to the defined features instead.

The problem here, of course is that the ERE alternation operator `|` doesn't exist at all in BRE, and the equivalent to ERE `+` is hideously ugly (it's `\{1,\}`). So you probably want to use ERE instead.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | sed 's/aaaaa|bbbbb/_/g'
    aaaaa
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | sed -E 's/aaaaa|bbbbb/_/g'
    _
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | sed -r 's/aaaaa|bbbbb/_/g'
    _
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | sed -E '/(aaaaa|bbbbb)/ s/ /_/g'
____aaaaa___
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | sed -E '/aaaaa|bbbbb/ s/ /_/g'
____aaaaa___
```

`or` is not a BRE (Basic Regular Expression). You need to specify `-E` for *extended* BRE.

See [Regex alternation/or operator (foo|bar) in GNU or BSD Sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/145404/74393)

## UPDATE

Why did grep work?

We can choose what kind of patttern we want to use with [grep](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?grep)

```
  -E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression
  -F, --fixed-strings       PATTERN is a set of newline-separated strings
  -G, --basic-regexp        PATTERN is a basic regular expression
  -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
  -e, --regexp=PATTERN      use PATTERN as a regular expression
```

By using these switches we can see that `grep` does indeed default to BRE and that the OP expression fails with ERE:

```
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | grep '\(aaaaa\|bbbbb\)'
    aaaaa
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | egrep '\(aaaaa\|bbbbb\)'
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | grep -E '\(aaaaa\|bbbbb\)'
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | grep -G '\(aaaaa\|bbbbb\)'
    aaaaa
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | grep -G 'aaaaa\|bbbbb'
    aaaaa
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | grep -G 'aaaaa|bbbbb'
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | grep -E 'aaaaa|bbbbb'
    aaaaa
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | grep -E 'aaaaa\|bbbbb'
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | grep -G 'bbbbb\|aaaaa'
    aaaaa
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | grep -E 'bbbbb\|aaaaa'
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | grep -G 'bbbbb|aaaaa'
$ echo '    aaaaa   ' | grep -E 'bbbbb|aaaaa'
    aaaaa
```

Both [grep](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?grep) and [sed](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sed) reference [re_format (7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format&sektion=7) which clearly states:

> Obsolete ("basic")    regular expressions differ in several respects.  `|'
>   is an ordinary character and there    is no equivalent for its functionality.

But it does seem that if we "escape the pipe" then we do indeed get the functionality. That certainly has a smell to it. Furthermore there seems to be recent breakage in that ballpark - see [regex(3): Add test to cover recent BRE regression](https://reviews.freebsd.org/D11577).

And there seems to be some work to replace the [regex](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Regex) in libc.

As Charles Duffy comments below

> because some tools implement nonstandard extensions wherein you can use a backslash to get otherwise-ERE-only behavior in a BRE context

I am used to very good documentation with FreeBSD. This means that I am unsure whether this is intended but not documented - or breakage.

Comment: But then why did `grep` work?

Comment: @TavianBarnes, ...because some tools (particularly including those GNU ships) implement nonstandard extensions wherein you can use a backslash to get otherwise-ERE-only behavior in a BRE context. The BRE standard doesn't guarantee that, though, so it's unwise to attempt to use it.

Comment: Really interesting to know if it is a bug or feature. The documentation contradicts the implementation.